# Postgres - is it possible to group by substring of one of my fields?

Tags: postgresql

This is my table:

```
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 actual_cost       | double precision        | not null
 chemical_id       | character varying(9)    | not null
 practice_id       | character varying(6)    | not null
```

I'd like to query results for a particular `practice_id`, and then sum the `actual_cost` by date and by the **first two characters** of the `chemical_id`. Is this possible in Postgres?

In other words, I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
processing_date   |    cost    |   chemical_id_substr
01-01-2010             1234        01
01-02-2010             4366        01
01-01-2010             3827        02
01-02-2010             8768        02
```

This is my current query, but it groups by the whole of `chemical_id`, not the substring:

```
    query = "SELECT SUM(actual_cost) as cost, processing_date, "
    query += "chemical_id as id FROM frontend_items"
    query += " WHERE practice_id=%s " 
    query += "GROUP BY processing_date, chemical_id"
    cursor.execute(query, (practice_id,))
```

I'm not sure how to change this to group by substring, or whether I should add a functional index, or whether I should just denormalise my table and add a new column. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `GROUP BY processing_date, left(chemical_id,2)` but you also need to use `left(chemical_id,2)` in the select list as well. Unrelated but: you are comparing for equality in your query: `WHERE practice_id=%s` so adding `%` (`practice_id + '%'`) to the parameter is wrong unless you want to make sure that only values that end with a `%` match

Comment: Does this work: `GROUP by processing_data, substring(chemical_id from 1 for 2)`. Note: you can't have `chemical_id` in the select list then.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, that works beautifully. Thanks also for the tip, I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this, but you also need to make sure the substring is used in the select list, not the complete column:

```
SELECT SUM(actual_cost) as cost, 
       processing_date, 
       left(chemical_id,2) as id --<< use the same expression here as in the GROUP BY
FROM frontend_items
WHERE practice_id= %s 
GROUP BY processing_date, left(chemical_id,2);
```

Comment: Though this' quite old, it was a as useful jumping point for me recently - you can save duplicating the function call in your grouping - for above you can `GROUP BY 2, 3` which uses the 2nd and 3rd fields you selected for grouping - can bite you if you change the order of fields in the select though :)